# Cant log in to backend of cloned Umbraco dev site

Tags: visual-studio, umbraco7

In Visual Studio Community 2017 (15.5.3), using NuGet, I have installed Umbraco 7.6.3 in an empty project, built it successfully, then opened default.aspx in a browser and followed the installation steps, successfully installing Umbraco and been able to log in and out of the back end ok.

In an effort to turn this installation of Umbraco into a clone of a solution I already had in Visual Studio I copied across the site specific files and folders from that installation, overwriting any duplicate files. I changed the connection string in web.config to point to a clone of the database used by the other installation. I then opened default.aspx again. I see the backend login screen at the url:

```
 http://localhost:50863/umbraco/AuthorizeUpgrade?redir=%2finstall%2f%3fredir%3dtrue%26url%3dhttp%253a%252f%252flocalhost%253a50863%252fdefault.aspx#/AuthorizeUpgrade?redir=%2Finstall%2F%3Fredir%3Dtrue%26url%3Dhttp%253a%252f%252flocalhost%253a50863%252fdefault.aspx
```

But when I enter the username and password that I know to be correct. I get a login failed message. If I try to use the forgotten password link and put in my email address then I am told that my password reset request failed.

Am I going about this the wrong way? What do I need to do to get this up and running? Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: I also asked this on the Our Umbraco forum, check [here](https://our.umbraco.org/forum/using-umbraco-and-getting-started/90162-cant-log-in-to-backend-of-cloned-dev-site) to see how that's going. No joy so far.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out. Found this in web.config:

```
 <add key="umbracoConfigurationStatus" value="" />
```

Changing it to

```
<add key="umbracoConfigurationStatus" value="7.6.3" />
```

meant that when I opened default.aspx I got the website rather than the login screen.

Updating the smtp settings in web.config to use the same as on the live site, ie to use our sendgrid account, meant that although I still got login failed when I tried to log in to the backend, the reset password option now worked. I was able to reset and get in.

Probably should have figured that out sooner but there you go.